# Trying to load the result of post into a div

Tags: jquery, cordova

I got this function:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cy4AZ/

The function is doing what it is supposed to do on the backend.

But I can't get it to "loop" through the results in the line saying:

```
$("#businesscardOffline")
    .empty()
    .html("Synchronized data for:<br>Name: "+name+"<br>Title: "+title)
    .fadeIn(1500)
    .delay(1000)
    .fadeOut(1500);
```

But in the line right after:

```
console.log("We are here!!! Name: " + name);
```

It's printing out to the console what I'm expecting.

The function is called from another JS function that is loaded on deviceready.

(This is running on a Android device, with Phonegap)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your `.fadeOut()` on the complete callback of the `.fadeIn()` , like this:

Empty the div **before** your loop enters:

```
$("#businesscardOffline").empty();
```

then inside the loop just append new content to the div:

```
$("#businesscardOffline").append("Synchronized data for:<br>Name: "+name+"<br>Title: "+title).fadeIn(1500, function() { $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut(1500); });
```

Comment: If I do that, it will only show up once.
At the monment I have two (2) results it should show

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you, you have no loop in there, your `$("#businesscardOffline")` element refers to only one element.

Comment: But it's contained in my for-sentence, thats running through the result of my SQL.
That's wha i empty() the div at first...

Comment: In that case use `.append()` instead of `.html()` , see my updated answer.

Comment: Also take care to empty the div just before entering the loop, so when inside the loop just append new content. See my edited answer.

Comment: With your answer, the DIV only displays once - with one result.

My idea was, that it should .fadeIn() show first result .delay().fadeOut()
Then, if more results, .fadeIn() show next result .delay().fadeOut()...

Comment: Updated fiddle:
$('#businesscardOffline').load(serverHttp + 'generateBusinessCard.php?random="+randomNumber+"&act=offlineMode&uid=' + visitorUID, function(data) {

TO:

$('#businesscardOfflineResult').load(serverHttp + 'generateBusinessCard.php?random="+randomNumber+"&act=offlineMode&uid=' + visitorUID, function(data) {

Now the #businesscardOffline should be empty at the beginning.